# Convert list into list of tuples of every two elements

Tags: python

How can I convert a list into a list of tuples? The tuples are composed of elements at even and odd indices of the list.For example, I have a list `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and needs to be converted to `[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)]`.

One method I can think of is as follows.

```
l = range(5)

out = []
it = iter(l)
for x in it:
    out.append((x, next(it)))

print(out)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Fun with `iter`:

```
it = iter(l)
[*zip(it, it)]  # list(zip(it, it))
# [(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)]
```

---

You can also slice in strides of 2 and `zip`:

```
[*zip(l[::2], l[1::2]))]
# [(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)]
```

Comment: For python3, add a list wrapper for the first approach `list(zip(it, it))`

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this with list comprehension without zip

```
l=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print([(l[i],l[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(l),2)])
#[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the use of Python's list comprehension.

```
l = range(5)
out = [tuple(l[i: i + 2]) for i in range(0, len(l), 2)]
# [(0, 1), (2, 3), (4,)]
```