# How can I split a string if a separator is repeated twice?

Tags: python, list, split, tuples

I need to transform a string 'apple/SP++/SW+orange/NNG++/FG+melon/SL+food/JKG' into a list of tuples [('apple', 'SP'), ('+', 'SW'), ('orange', 'NNG'), ('+', 'FG), ('melon', 'SL'), ('food', 'JKG')]
I think, first I need to split a string with separator '+', and then split with a separator '/'.

But the problem is that there are two plus signs. First plus sign I need to take as a separator and second one I need to save. If split a string simply with a separator '+', it removes all plus signs:

```
s = 'apple/SP++/SW+orange/NNG++/FG+melon/SL+food/JKG'
x = s.split('+')
print(x)
#['apple/SP', '', '/SW', 'orange/NNG', '', '/FG', 'melon/SL', 'food/JKG']
```

If split with a separator '++':

```
s = 'apple/SP++/SW+orange/NNG++/FG+melon/SL+food/JKG'
splitted_s = s.plit('++')
print(x)
#['apple/SP', '/SW+orange/NNG', '/FG+melon/SL+food/JKG']
```

I have no idea of how to come to the result of [('apple', 'SP'), ('+', 'SW'), ('orange', 'NNG'), ('+', 'FG), ('melon', 'SL'), ('food', 'JKG')]

Comment: I think you meant `s.split('++')` in the second code example

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression:

- `\+(?=\+)` - plus followed by another plus (positive lookahead)
- `|` - or
- `\+(?!/)` - plus not followed by a forward slash (negative lookahead)

Code:

```
import re

pattern = r"\+(?=\+)|\+(?!/)"
string = "apple/SP++/SW+orange/NNG++/FG+melon/SL+food/JKG"

print([s.split("/") for s in re.split(pattern, string)])
```

Output:

```
[['apple', 'SP'], ['+', 'SW'], ['orange', 'NNG'], ['+', 'FG'], ['melon', 'SL'], ['food', 'JKG']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
s = 'apple/SP++/SW+orange/NNG++/FG+melon/SL+food/JKG'
x = s.replace("++", "+/*")
x = x.split('+')
x = [item.replace("*", "+") for item in x]
x = [item.split('/') for item in x]
y = []
for item in x:
    y += item
#remove the list items that are ''
for i in range(y.count('')):
    y.remove('')
# modified from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53990075/convert-list-into-list-of-tuples-of-every-two-elements
out = []
it = iter(y)
for i in range(len(y)):
    if i % 2 == 0 and i < len(y) - 1:
        out.append((y[i], y[i + 1]))
print(out)
```

Result:

```
[('apple', 'SP'), ('+', 'SW'), ('orange', 'NNG'), ('+', 'FG'), ('melon', 'SL'), ('food', 'JKG')]
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to the one proposed by Paul, but I think mine is simpler.

```
import re

s = "apple/SP++/SW+orange/NNG++/FG+melon/SL+food/JKG"
pattern = r"((?:\+|\w+)\/\w+)"
res = [tuple(m.split("/")) for m in re.findall(pattern, s)]
```